# SMS Alert API Validation in laravel

Tags: laravel

public function verifyotp(Request $request)
{
$mobile=$request->mobilenumber;

```
$otp=$request->otp;


$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$tem='https://www.smsalert.co.in/api/mverify.json?apikey=#&mobileno=';
$cod='&code=';
$msg=($tem.$mobile.$cod.$otp);
$res=$client->request('POST', $msg);
(string) $res->getBody();


if($res->getBody(['description']=== "['desc']:Code does not match.")
{
    echo 'Code Not Matched';
}

elseif(($res->getBody(['description'] === "['desc']:Code Matched successfully."))
{
    echo  'Code Matched;
}
```

}

I have get response from api.I got Two response

one is like this

{
"status": "success",
"description": {
"desc": "Code does not match."
}
}

Second  like this

{
"status": "success",
"description": {
"desc": "Code matched successfully."   }
}
In This response i want to read "desc" on my controller

How to check desc using if condition ?

Comment: Please add more information about your question. Information such as the API you use and a code snippet of what you tried will be useful :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract and access data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-to-extract-and-access-data-from-json-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use json_decode function like this :

```
$result = json_decode($response);
echo $result->description->desc;
```

[see this for detail](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Done...

Comment: json_decode(): Argument #1 ($json) must be of type string, GuzzleHttp\Client given

THis is the error I got.

Comment: json is a kind of string. if you're response is a json type , you can parse this with json_decode.